# How do I return the TextView without ID's using .append()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

noobie developing a linear algebra app here for my first app, I am trying to use the Textview.append() to return some calculations based on the users entry. But since I am using .append for my print method, it shows up with these Id numbers.

Image of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxHuD.jpg

Output_ele is referenced by:

```
output_ele = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputLabel);
```

The following is the method I am using to print my results.

```
public final void stringprint(String[][] orig, int rowmax, int columnmax)
   {
   for (int i = 1; i <= rowmax; i++) {
       for (int j = 1; j <= columnmax; j++) {
           String entry = String.valueOf(orig[i][j]);

           String tab = "";

           for (int k = 1; k <= 7 - entry.length(); k++) {
               tab = tab + " ";
           }

           output_ele.append(output_ele + entry + tab);
       }

       output_ele.append(output_ele + "\n");
   }
```

And this is the code that is run when the button is clicked; it calls the methods and prints them to the output_ele label. Also rowmax, columnmax and orig are all defined in their respective methods.:

```
output_ele.append(output_ele + "Determinant: " + determinant(orig, rowmax, columnmax) + "\n");

    //roundmatrix(orig, rowmax, columnmax);
    //roundmatrix(transpose, columnmax, rowmax);

    output_ele.append(output_ele + "Row Reduced Echelon From: \n");
    //+= output_ele +  "Row Reduced Echelon Form: \n";
    stringprint(rationalize(orig, rowmax, columnmax), rowmax, columnmax);

    output_ele.append(output_ele + "\n");

    if ((rowmax == columnmax) && (determinant(orig, rowmax, columnmax) != 0))
    {
        output_ele.append("Inverse Matrix\n");
        stringprint(rationalize(inverse, rowmax, columnmax), rowmax, columnmax);
    }
    else
    {
        output_ele.append("Matrix is not invertible.\n");
    }

    output_ele.append("\nBasis of Rowspace:");
    output_ele.append(stringrowspace(rationalize(orig, rowmax, columnmax), rowmax, columnmax));

    output_ele.append("\nBasis of Columnspace:");
    output_ele.append( stringrowspace(rationalize(transpose, columnmax, rowmax), columnmax, rowmax));

    output_ele.append("\nBasis of Nullspace:");
    output_ele.append(nullspace(orig, rowmax, columnmax));

    output_ele.append("\nBasis of Left Nullspace:");
    output_ele.append(nullspace(transpose, columnmax, rowmax));
}
```

The issue (I think) is using the print method and I dont want those pesky Id numbers showing up (as seen in imgur link). How would I go about doing that?

Also while I have you here, what would be the easiest way to make the EditText textboxes disappear after a button is pressed??

Any help appreciated..

Comment: You should post less code so pepole will read your question and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text from a `TextView` you should use `output_ele.getText().toString()`, if you treat `output_ele` as a string, you get all the object information you are seeing.

eg.

```
output_ele.append(output_ele + "\n");
```

should be

```
output_ele.append(output_ele.getText().toString() + "\n");
```

This will, however, duplicate the entire contents of the `TextView`, you are aware append will keep the original contents and *append* to it right?

**EDIT**

upon further investigation, your problem will probably be fixed by simply removing the bolded lines:

output_ele.append(**output_ele +** "Determinant: " + determinant(orig, rowmax, columnmax) + "\n");

output_ele.append(**output_ele +** "Row Reduced Echelon From: \n");

output_ele.append(**output_ele +** "\n");

Comment: To clarify, I am getting the input from EditText textboxes and want to display it to the output_ele which is a TextView.
I first used .setText() and found that it didnt keep the previous contents. What do you think would be the best way to display the output?

Comment: There are no `EditText`'s in the code you posted, but it's possible you have similar problems there.  Seems like append would be fine, but you have no reason to add the original contents of the text view in that case.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I have attched an image link to what my editTexts look like (too long to reply in a comment): http://imgur.com/SghW3tR.  And it continues for each box for each row and column. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: See my edit, if you remove the output_ele from your append statements I think it will clear up your output.  If you want to access the text of the output_ele, see my original answer and access it using `getText()` as you are for your edit text's in the screen shot you posted.

Comment: Thanks very much for that help it worked, I feel silly for forgetting how .append works. Another question, any ideas how I would hide the EditText's after the button is clicked so that the label is the only thing showing?

Comment: `row1col1_ele.setVisibility(View.GONE);` ...etc

Comment: That works great thanks, another quick question: how would I display the output values without decimals. This is what it outputs right now: http://imgur.com/Ii8hz2g

Comment: Going a little past the original scope of the question, but if you don't want decimals you can either use numberformatter to remove them, or just parse.Integer instead of parse.Double